# Aggregation with distinct count in Spark structured streaming throwing error

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

i am trying to get unique id for group of Parentgroup,childgroup and MountingType in Spark structured streaming.

Code: the below code is throwing error

```
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minutes")
          val aggDF = JSONDF.groupBy("Parentgroup","childgroup","MountingType")
       .agg(countDistinct("id"))

Error:
Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark
```

may someone please help me how to do aggregate and write to the csv in structured streaming.
Thanks a lot

Data:

```
{"id":"7CE3A7CA","Faulttime":1544362500,"name":"Sony","Parentgroup":"TV","childgroup":"Other","MountingType":"SurfaceMount"}
    {"id":"7CE3A7CA","Faulttime":1544362509,"name":"Sony","Parentgroup":"TV","childgroup":"Other","MountingType":"SurfaceMount"}
    {"id":"010004FF,"Faulttime":1551339188,"name":"Philips","Parentgroup":"Light","childgroup":"Other","MountingType":"Solder"}
    {"id":"010004FF","Faulttime":1551339188,"name":"Sony","Parentgroup":"TV","childgroup":"Other","MountingType":"Solder"}
    {"id":"010004FF,"Faulttime":1551339191,"name":"Sansui","Parentgroup":"AC","childgroup":"Other","MountingType":"SurfaceMount"}
    {"id":"CE361405","Faulttime":1552159061,"name":"Hyndai","Parentgroup":"SBAR","childgroup":"Other","MountingType":"SurfaceMount"}
    {"id":"CE361405","Faulttime":1552159061,"name":"sony","Parentgroup":"TV","childgroup":"Other","MountingType":"SurfaceMount"}
    {"id":"7BE446C0","Faulttime":1553022095,"name":"Sony","Parentgroup":"TV","childgroup":"Other","MountingType":"Solder"}
    {"id":"7BE446C0","Faulttime":1553022095,"name":"Philips","Parentgroup":"LIGHT","childgroup":"Other","MountingType":"Solder"}
```

Comment: please provide error details ..

Comment: @kavetiraviteja: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;

Comment: @kavetiraviteja: Please help me...if possible.

Comment: please check my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Group By operations need to specify **window or time period** in spark streaming.

Try this

```
psuedo code    
val JSONDF = df.withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minutes")
val aggDF = JSONDF.groupBy(window("timestamp", "5 minutes", "1 minutes")).agg(countDistinct("id"),$"Parentgroup",$"childgroup",$"MountingType")
```

Reference :
https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/08/event-time-aggregation-watermarking-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html

Comment: Many Thanks.... even i have imported import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._.... still getting error like " Cannot resolve overload method window.

Comment: i have used scala instead of python.

Comment: please check window function here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.html